# Angular2 directives is not shown

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-directives

I have problem with showing directives in my Angular2 APP,

I have imported the Class and add it to the component using Directives,

But some how its dont work, I have tried everything, I have change the code something like 100 times, thanks for your help!
https://github.com/eshk12/Snake

Comment: Could you show us any error that appear on the browser's console?

Comment: hey, there is no error in the console..

Comment: Well.. You are not displaying anything because your app component's template doesn't have the snake directive anywhere

Comment: yes it is, https://github.com/eshk12/Snake/blob/master/app/templates/app-components.html
as you can see its write in the bottom
@RicardoLeon

Answer (score 0):

It should be `templateUrl` instead of `template` in your snake component.

Comment: I changed it for the debugging its no make a diffrence if i just want to see some text.

Answer (score 0):

Change your snake component's selector to "snake". Then you would display a directive like

```
<snake> </snake>
```

On your App Component

Comment: You don't seem to be following the tutorial. Either the transpiler would throw an error or the browser's console